# Confirmation Box OnClientClick in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, confirmation, onclientclick

I'm trying to work on this website wherein I need to filter the data which are to be inserted into the database. For instance, I need to insert 'Hello World' to the database. However, it already exists. Therefore, I need to pop-up a confirmation box saying "The string Hello World already exists in the database. Are you sure you want to continue?"

My problem is that I don't know in which place in my code should I include my confirmation message. Please see below for referrence:

```
private bool CheckData(string myString)
{
    //Check database if myString already exists. 
    return;
}

private void btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckData(myString)
    //If the above is true, then the confirmation box should appear.
    //Do something to save myString to the database.
}
```

I'm programatically adding an OnClientClick Event handler to my button using the code below:

```
btnSave.OnClientClick = "confirmation('The string " + myString + " already exists in the database. Are you sure you want to continue?')";
```

My problem is basically what is the best way to handle this kind of scenario? Since I can't place this code on the btnSave_Click event (it will add the OnClientClick handler but it will only fire the next time the button was clicked).

Comment: you can use btnSave.OnClientClick="window.alert('your message')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/csharp/1dca3c46-4bb9-4a46-a7bb-b909bb1d137d/user-confirmation-from-code-behind.aspx

Answer (score 0):

to do this via ajax, have the onClientClick call a js function that calls a .net handler to check if the file exists, and either:

1. return true if no file exists so the postback occurs
2. if the file already exists, popup a confirmation box and return the result of the confirmation box

otherwise, you can check if the file exists in the postback, but then you'll have to display a message and another confirm button to allow the user to overwrite the file.  It will create two postbacks if the user decides to upload and overwrite an existing file.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. However, I'm new to js functions. Can you please elaborate more on how this could be achieved? Also, i'll be more appreciative and eager to see a simple code block example for this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

//add this function in your program

```
public static void ShowAlertMessage(string error)
{
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
        if (page != null)
        {
            error = error.Replace("'", "\'");
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "err_msg", "alert('" + error + "');", true);
        }
    }
```

//check the value returned by your function

```
private void btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool flag=CheckData(myString);
    //If the above is true, then the confirmation box should appear.
    //Do something to save myString to the database.
if (flag==true)
{
ShowAlertMessage("The data Could not be added");
}
else
{
//do the desired operation of adding in the database.
}

}
```

Hope it helps..